# const franc = require('franc'); Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a JS for guessing the language using franc and langs package, but it's always showing this error as shown in the title

here's my code

```js
import franc from 'franc';
 
import langs from 'langs';


function guessLanguage(text) {
  const langCode = franc(text);
  if (langCode === 'und') {
    return 'Cannot guess language';
  } else {
    const language = langs.where('3', langCode);
    return language.name;
  }
}

// Example usage:
const inputText = 'Bonjour tout le monde';
const guessedLanguage = guessLanguage(inputText);
console.log(``The input text is in ${guessedLanguage}``);
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpSRi.png)

I try the es6 module "type": "module" to my package json but the error is still the same. or is there any new codes to solve this problem using this franc and langs, tysm in advance

Comment: Neither your code or the code of either of the libraries contains the statement `const franc = require('franc');` so it's not clear where that's coming from. Note: the correct way of importing `franc` is `import {franc, francAll} from 'franc'` according to [the documentation](https://github.com/wooorm/franc).

Comment: franc is ESM only. You need to turn off whatever tool is converting your import and exports to commonjs.

Comment: I did it now but there is a new error, it say (node:19096) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.
json or use the .mjs extension. 
import {franc, francAll} from 'franc'
  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: im only using vscode and gitbash. what tool should i turn off and how to export that to commonjs

Comment: i think its a backend code for node js? cant run on browser so the way you initialized project? follow a tutorial for backend nodejs begginner project with type script, import this there